# How to pass input parameters through ajax to struts2 action classes without appending parameters in url

Tags: java, ajax, struts2

I have a web application on java Struts 2,ajax,
I have to call action class through ajax with some input parameters, for that 
 i am appending parameters in url due to this we are facing security issues. 
Since we are appending parameters in url, the values are coming in url in logs.

Below is my code:

```
$.ajax({
            url : 'TransposeDataServlet.servlet?pan='+panVal+'&ay1='+ay1+'&ay2='+ay2,
            type:'post', 
            cache: false,
            success : function(result) {
                status=result;                  
                console.log('Data came : '+status);
    }
        });
```

So please suggest how can we pass input parameters using ajax call without appending parameters in url.
For any suggestions.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Put the data in the `data` property? This is covered in most any jQuery Ajax post tutorial, and is not related to S2 at all.

Answer (score 0):

There's an AJAX setting called `data` that you can use to do what you want.

```
$.ajax({
            url : 'TransposeDataServlet.servlet',
            type:'post',
            data: {pan: panVal, ay1: ay1, ay2: ay2},
            cache: false,
            success : function(result) {
                status=result;                  
                console.log('Data came : '+status);
    }
        });
```

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is the full documentation.